# Error when I use API for deleting comments instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

When I use the API for deleting comments I get an error

status:500  -> DATA=Oops, an error occurred

Why this error please? how to solve it

thanks a lot

Comment: 500 status is `Internal Server Error` and you cant do anything about it. maybe you should inform them for bug fix. how are you calling the API? maybe editing your question and adding your code may help us guide you better

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, could you give me the link that i can inform them or email please